# How to be able to handle both cases of element exists and does not exist?

Tags: javascript, cypress, cypress-conditional-testing

I would like to have the ability to handle the situation of both cases: the element exists and does not exist.

All my trials ended with an exception when it didn't find the item and therefore I couldn't do the stuff I wanted in this case or errors that using then.catch or then.fail are not valid.

For example, my last trial is:

```
cy.get('.ant-breadcrumb-link').then(($element) => {
    if ($element.is(':exists')) {
        // Element exists, perform actions
        cy.log('Element exists');
        // ... your actions when the element exists ...
    } else {
        // Element does not exist, perform other actions
        cy.log('Element does not exist');
        // ... your actions when the element does not exist ...
    }
});
```

So when the `cy.get('.ant-breadcrumb-link')` fails I don't get into the `then()` section.

How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: `$element.length > 0` perhaps?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can always leverage `jQuery` when you face issues with the checking the existence of the element. I would get the `document` object using ***[`cy.document`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/document)*** and use ***[`Cypress.$`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/$#Syntax)***(`jquery` equivalent in cypress) for the same. A sample would look like:

```js
cy.document().then((document) => {
  const $element = Cypress.$('.ant-breadcrumb-link', document);
  
  if ($element.length > 0) {
    // ... your actions when the element exists ...
  } else {
    // ... your actions when the element does not exist ...
  }
});
```

**SIDENOTE:**

`cy.get()` will keep on searching for the element and [throws an exception](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress#When-Elements-Are-Missing) if the element is not found.